# How to clear form fields and rerender form with RichFaces

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm stuck at pretty simple task: I have a search form where the search criteria are stored is SearchCriteriaSession bean, so it could be remembered and pre-filled. And I want to add reset button to that form that would:

1) clear the criteria from bean, therefore call clearSearchCriteria() method of the bean
2) rerender the form, so the fields would be empty

Here's my code and I have no idea why it's not working:

search.xhtml

```
...
<h:form id="criteriaForm">
    <div class="controls">
        <h:inputText type="text" id="testName" value="#handlingBean.criteria.testName}" />
    </div>

    //more input fields but with same format

    <div class="form-actions">
        <r:commandButton action="#searchCriteriaSession.clearSearchCriteria}" value="Reset" render="@form :criteriaForm" />
    </div>
</h:form>
...
```

The *searchCriteriaSession.clearSearchCriteria* just clears criteria. When I debug it I see it correctly cleared. Even when I refresh the page the form clears, so the problem is that the *render* attribute is not working correctly, I guess.

Does anybody can please help me?

P.S.: I'm using RichFaces, this maven artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.compat</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-rich</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.0.Alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `render` attribute needs only `@form`

```
<r:commandButton action="#searchCriteriaSession.clearSearchCriteria}" value="Reset" render="@form" />
```

Comment: I finally found the problem, it wasn't even in RichFaces, it was in bean's logic :-( Despite that, you're absolutely correct, there's no need for :criteriaForm. Thanks!